# Unknown entity: java.lang.Long in JUnit test

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I am trying to create a JUnit test case that tests two overridden methods. I have narrowed down the problem to the exact line of code but cannot for the life of me figure out why this stack trace is occurring. Here is the method in my class:

```
@Override
public void deleteUserTicketEntity(long ticketNumber)
{
    //UserTicketEntity deleteTicket = (UserTicketEntity) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(UserTicketEntity.class, ticketNumber);
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(ticketNumber);
}
```

Here is the test Method in my JUnit class:

```
@Test
public void testDeleteTicket() throws Exception
{
    long Id = 4;
    long _Id = 87;
    UserTicketEntity ticket = userTicketDao.getUserTicketEntity(Id);
    assertNotNull(ticket);
    System.out.println("testDeleteTicket: START");
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    userTicketDao.deleteUserTicketEntity(ticket);
    System.out.println("testDeleteTicket: ticket deleted");
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    System.out.println("testDeleteTicket: FINISHED");
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    long _ticketNumber = 1;
    UserTicketEntity ticketTwo = userTicketDao.getUserTicketEntity(_Id);
    assertNotNull(ticketTwo);
    assertNotNull(_ticketNumber);
    System.out.println("testDeleteUserTicketEntity: START");
    userTicketDao.deleteUserTicketEntity(_ticketNumber);
    System.out.println("testDeleteUserTicketEntity: ticket deleted");
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    System.out.println("testDeleteUserTicketEntity: FINISHED");
}
```

I have narrowed down that the line of code in question is:

`userTicketDao.deleteUserTicketEntity(_ticketNumber);`

And here is the stacktrace:

```
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.863 sec <<< FAILURE!
testDeleteTicket(com.ticketingsystem.dao.UserTicketDAOTest)  Time elapsed: 0.03 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Long
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:924)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:863)
    at com.ticketingsystem.dao.UserTicketDAOImpl.deleteUserTicketEntity(UserTicketDAOImpl.java:55)
    at com.ticketingsystem.dao.UserTicketDAOTest.testDeleteTicket(UserTicketDAOTest.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  testDeleteTicket(com.ticketingsystem.dao.UserTicketDAOTest): Unknown entity: java.lang.Long

Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hibernate `Session.delete(Object object)` doesn't delete by ID, it needs an instance of your `Entity` instead.

Just change your DAO method to accept the object itself or instantiate a new object to delete.

```
public void deleteUserTicketEntity(UserTicketEntity ticket) {
    // delete passed in object
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(ticket);
}

public void deleteUserTicketEntityById(long ticketNumber) {
    // instantiate new object w/ ID, then delete
    final UserTicketEntity deleteTicket = new UserTicketEntity();
    deleteTicket.setId(ticketNumber);
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(deleteTicket);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty much it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to delete the ticketNumber, which is a Long and not mapped. What you need to delete is your UserTicketEntity. You need to load it first, then delete.

See: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-basics-3-ways-to-delete-an-entity-from-the-datastore

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to delete a long, which isn't a mapped entity that Hibernate knows about. There are three ways to delete an object.

#### Transient Session.delete()

This method expects a transient object that can be matched to a persistent entity. For example:

```
@Override
public void deleteUserTicketEntity (long ticketNumber )
{
    UserTicketEntity deleteTicket = new UserTicketEntity();
    deleteTicket.setTicketNumber( ticketNumber );
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete( deleteTicket );
}
```

There is an issue though. This will throw a `ConstraintViolationException` if the `UserTicketEntity` is associated with another entity in the database.

#### Persistent Session.delete()

This time the method is expecting an object previously loaded into the current Session. This will trigger any cascading deletion necessary to avoid the `ConstraintViolationException`. For example:

```
@Override
public void deleteUserTicketEntity(long ticketNumber)
{
    Serializable ticketNum = new Long( ticketNumber );
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Object deleteTicket = session.load( UserTicketEntity.class, ticketNum );
    if( deleteTicket != null)
    {
        session.delete(ticketNumber);
    }
}
```

#### HQL

This involves creating an HQL query that will perform the deletion for us. This will still throw a `ConstraintViolationException` if there are associations to the `UserTicketEntity` but you can simply write a second query to delete those associations. Example below:

```
@Override
public void deleteUserTicketEntity(long ticketNumber)
{
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery( "delete UserTicketEntity where ticketNumber = :num" );
    query.setParameter( "num", new Long( ticketNumber ) );

    if( query.executeUpdate() > 0 )
    {
        System.out.println( "Ticket " + ticketNumber + " was removed." );
    }
}
```

For more inforamtion see this [CodeJava.net](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-basics-3-ways-to-delete-an-entity-from-the-datastore) article.